# Self Organizing Map (SOM) Implementation

Tags: c++, c, som, self-organizing-maps

I'm looking for a C, C++ or Java based SOM implementation with licensing applicable for commercial use (non-zero cost is okay).

So far I'm aware that there exists SOM_PAK (from Kohonen), but the licensing forbids commercial use.

Is anyone aware of alternative implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this, it's BSD licensed.

http://knnl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 - thanks for paying attention to my language and license request -- this looks great.  For others reading this question/answer, there's also a Java version by the same guys here: http://jknnl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi, do you know how to run it with big data set? Private computer can not handle such big data set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a C# version here: [MPerfect](http://www.mperfect.net/aiSomPic).